# Elements of order three in $GL_3(2)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How do I go about finding elements of order 3 in $GL_3(2)$? I'm currently trying to show that the automorphism group of a Klein 4-group induced by conjugation in $GL_3(2)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ so am attempting to find an element of the normaliser with order three in order to show the desired conclusion. But I'm struggling to find such an element. Any help (even another method I might be able to use) would be much appreciated.

The specific klein-4 group I am working with is that generated by $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ 
and 
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Comment: The obvious elements of order three are those permuting the base vectors cyclically

Comment: those didn't work sadly!

Comment: There is only one conjugacy class of elements of order 3 in your group. This means that up to conjugation, Hagen's answer is right... Maybe, you could give us explicitely the subgroup $V$ you are working with... Anyway the element of order 3 you are looking for is a conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to choose an element that looks like
$$\left( \begin{array}{cr} A & 0\\ 0\ \ \ 0 & 1\end{array} \right)$$
where $A$ is any element of order $3$ in ${\rm GL}(2,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the action of your two matrices on the 7 nonzero column vectors. Each fixes 3 vectors, and exchanges two pairs of vectors. So $V$ acts trivially on 3 vectors and acts on the other 4.

For example, $\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$ shows that that element in $V$ fixes that vector.

An element of order 3 which normalizes your group V should fix one of the 4 vectors moved by V and rotate the other 3, as it would as the normalizer of $V$ in $S_4$ on 4 points. This should be enough information to explicitly find such an element of order 3. One such matrix is
\begin{pmatrix}                0 & 1 & 0 \\                1 & 1 & 1 \\                0 & 0 & 1                \end{pmatrix}

Comment: sorry could you explain which you mean as the 7 base vectors?

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Good point, as these don't fix the same 3. I believe for this you can adapt the method for this case by using row vectors instead of column vectors.